# How to check a webdriver is in line with browser version in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-manager

Before I run my TestNG suite I would like to check that Chrome and Edge webdriver are up to date and stop the TestNG suite if the browser can't be lauched.

My code so far is,

```
    EdgeDriver driver2 = new EdgeDriver();
    StartBrowser.driver(driver2, prop2);
    LogFile.logfile("Perform Second logon to Edge Browser");

    if(!LogonUser.logonButton(driver2).isEnabled())
    {
        LogFile.logfile("Logon button not detected for Edge, assuming webdriver is out of date");
        System.exit(2);
    }

    LogFile.logfile("Logon button detected, webdriver is assumed to be valid for Edge");
```

At the point this line, "EdgeDriver driver2 = new EdgeDriver();" runs, it goes into the TestInvoker.class and the test stops and goes on to the next @test.

Is there a way of testing the webdriver before instantiating it?

Or perhaps I'm looking at the solution in the wrong way?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [WebDriverManager](https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/).
This will insure your `WebDriver` is always updated automatically.

Comment: Thank you, this is so much easier.

For reference this site, https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/webdrivermanager/, helped me to add the external jar files, then use the "import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;" to reference WebDriverManager to call "WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();", which updates the webdriver for me.

No more checking browser version and getting the correct webdriver and downloading etc.